# Key in XML search with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have XML Code:

```
<TestCases>
    <TestCase>
        <TestCaseElement>
            <Name><![CDATA[IP_EXTDEVICE]]></Name>
            <Tags>
                <Tag><![CDATA[Upperlimit]]></Tag>
            </Tags>
            <TaggedValues>
                <TaggedValue key="Upperlimit">
                    <value><![CDATA[4]]></value>
                </TaggedValue>
            </TaggedValues>
        </TestCaseElement>
    </TestCase>
</TestCases>
```

How can i select with XSLT 
the Value 4 ?

---

```
<xsl:template name="selectOwnTaggedValue">
    <xsl:value-of select="[normalize-space(value)]" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="TestCases/TestCase/TestCaseElement">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="selectOwnTaggedValue[TaggedValues[TaggedValue key="Upperlimit"]" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

My XSL-Code is not valid because i dont know how to select the value **4** in my transformation

Thx in advance

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/TestCase"/>
</xsl:template>
      
<xsl:template match="TestCase">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(
   'The upper limit for ',
  TestCaseElement/Name,
   ' is ',
  TestCaseElement/TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='Upperlimit']/value,
  '&#x0A;'
   )"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Update

The output from running this style-sheet against the sample input is ...

```
The upper limit for IP_EXTDEVICE is 4
```

Let me know if you want a different output.

Comment: thank you, alas i dont geht the result i need. Why do you think i have to apply with "*/TestCase"/ ? I am already in TestCaseElement so i would best call it with an parameter like Upperlimit so that i can call the template  - you named it **TestCase** - for other TaggedValues too.

Comment: quote: The <xsl:apply-templates> element applies a template to the current element or to the current element's child nodes. **from** here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_apply_templates.asp

Comment: @arphex By the way the w3schools page you quote is wrong. That website gets a lot of things wrong. Be careful about it.

Comment: @ Sean, thank you i will answer in a new anser because of code-input

Comment: Hi Sean, i merged your input with my requirements in a new answer please have a look @ it. Thank you

Comment: @arphex Ok, I will have a look at it. But please tell me: What is your expected output? And what version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: i am using altova 2012 xslt processor. my answer is @ the end. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='Upperlimit']/value
```

This selects the element.

```
string(/*/TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='Upperlimit']/value)
```

This produces the string value of the first selected element.

```
/*/TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='Upperlimit']/value/text()
```

This selects all text-node childtren of all selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think to hold it generic it is better to call the template with a parameter. Am i thinking correct?

Ok this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<TestCases>
<TestCase>
<TestCaseElement>
<Name><![CDATA[IP_EXTDEVICE]]></Name>
        <Tags>
            <Tag><![CDATA[Upperlimit]]></Tag>
            <Tag><![CDATA[Lowerlimit]]></Tag>
        </Tags>
        <TaggedValues>
            <TaggedValue key="Upperlimit">
                <value><![CDATA[4]]></value>
            </TaggedValue>
            <TaggedValue key="Lowerlimit">
                <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
            </TaggedValue>
        </TaggedValues>

        <Role><![CDATA[TESTSTEP]]></Role>
</TestCaseElement>
<and many more TestCaseElements/>
</TestCase>
</TestCases>
```

Now i need in my output Upper and lower Limit and best would be in a generic template so i would try now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output name="text" method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
    <xsl:template name="OwnTaggedValues">
        <xsl:value-of select="TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='taggedvalue']/value" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="TestCases/TestCase/TestCaseElement[Role = 'TESTSTEP']">
            <xsl:call-template name="OwnTaggedValues">
                </xsl:with-param name="taggedvalue" select="Upperlimit">
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text>And now the Lowerlimit</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="OwnTaggedValues">
                </xsl:with-param name="taggedvalue" select="Lowerlimit">
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is really exactly my issue :-). Thank you in advance sean and all others

Comment: Can you show your expected output please? I will not be able to understand what you want until you show a listing of your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Hi my solution is now:

in xsl:

```
<xsl:template name="Unit" > 
    <xsl:value-of select="TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='Unit']/value"/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Precision" > 
    <xsl:value-of select="TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='Precision']/value"/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Upperlimit" > 
    <xsl:value-of select="TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='Upperlimit']/value"/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Lowerlimit" > 
    <xsl:value-of select="TaggedValues/TaggedValue[@key='Lowerlimit']/value"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

called with

```
<xsl:call-template name="Unit"/>
```

on this xml:

```
<TestCaseElement>
        <Name><![CDATA[ini_Alle-Schütze_OFF_V1-0]]></Name>
        <Tags>
            <Tag><![CDATA[Upperlimit]]></Tag>
            <Tag><![CDATA[Precision]]></Tag>
            <Tag><![CDATA[Lowerlimit]]></Tag>
            <Tag><![CDATA[Unit]]></Tag>
        </Tags>

        <TaggedValues>
            <TaggedValue key="Upperlimit">
                <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
            </TaggedValue>
            <TaggedValue key="Precision">
                <value><![CDATA[0]]></value>
            </TaggedValue>
            <TaggedValue key="Lowerlimit">
                <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
            </TaggedValue>
            <TaggedValue key="Unit">
                <value><![CDATA[ok]]></value>
            </TaggedValue>
        </TaggedValues>
   </TestCaseElement>
```

and my desired output:

> is the value that is in the respective value.

thank you sean, your solution with the @key was the right hint :-)